# javascript canvas: изображение не выводится

Tags: javascript, canvas, изображения

Подскажите, почему при таком коде:

```
<html>

<body>

<canvas id = 'c01' style = "width: 800; border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("c01");

var ctx  = canvas.getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {

    canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;

    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    ctx.lineWidth = "6";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.rect(canvas.width / 4, canvas.height / 4, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

    ctx.stroke();   
};

image.src = "https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2019/03/31/13/20190331135912200/pic_5bfd003894e22bb0d70b775286b96a4f.jpg";

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

выводится изображение и поверх него прямоугольник - ВСЕ ок

А при таком:

```
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("c01");

var ctx  = canvas.getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {

    canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;
};

image.src = "https://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2019/03/31/13/20190331135912200/pic_5bfd003894e22bb0d70b775286b96a4f.jpg";

ctx.beginPath();

ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

ctx.lineWidth = "6";
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.rect(canvas.width / 4, canvas.height / 4, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

ctx.stroke();   

</script>
```

канвас строется нужного размера (с изображение), но само изображение не отрисовывается, а прямоугольник мигает на секунду и исчезает

это связано с тем, что изображение ещё не успевает загрузиться (асинхронный image.src)?

и как корректно все делать?

если несколько изображений, то вряд ли onload придется несколько делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно дождаться, пока все загрузиться, и только потом рисовать:

```js
let imagesCanvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let imgCtx = imagesCanvas.getContext('2d');
let images = ['keyboard.jpg', 'star.jpg','leaves.jpg' ]
let loaded = [];

load();// загружаем картинки

function load() {
  let name = images.shift();
  let img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  // вызываем загрузку следующей картинки, пока они все не будут загружены, 
  // тут надо предусмотреть onerror, и отрисовку, когда они все загрузятся
  img.onload = () => add() | images.length ? load() : requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  img.src = `https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/${name}`
  
  // добавляем инфо о картинке в массив
  function add() {
    loaded.push({
      name: name, img: img,
      x: 50+loaded.length*120,
      y: 5+30*loaded.length,
      w: img.width/2, h: img.height/2
    });
  }
}
   
function draw(){
   loaded.forEach((img, i) => {
      // рисуем картинки на канве
      imgCtx.drawImage(img.img, img.x , img.y, img.w, img.h);
})}
```

```css
body{margin:0}
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="170"></canvas>
```

А еще можно в каждом onload вызвать перерисовку всего кадра (`draw()`), не оптимально, но код проще будет:

```js
let imagesCanvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let imgCtx = imagesCanvas.getContext('2d');
let images = ['keyboard.jpg', 'star.jpg','leaves.jpg' ]
let loaded = [];

images.forEach(name => {
  let img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  img.src = `https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/${name}`
  img.onload = () => {
    loaded.push({
      img: img,
      x: 50 + loaded.length*120,
      y: 5 + 30*loaded.length,
      w: img.width/2, 
      h: img.height/2
    });
    draw();
  };
})

function draw() {
   loaded.forEach(i => imgCtx.drawImage(i.img, i.x , i.y, i.w, i.h));
}
```

```css
body{margin:0}
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="170"></canvas>
```